# array of text files

Tags: java, arrays, file

is it possible to create an array of text files ?

lets say i have a folder which contains a set of 20 text files.

I would like to store the text file inside the array to do some processing and iterate thru all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Try Apache Commons IO.

```
Iterator it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(dir, new String[]{"txt"},false);
while(it.hasNext()){
    File txtFile = it.next();
}
```

There is also a similar method that will return `Collection<File>` instead of an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

You can use [FileFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) to just get *.txt from all files.

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array of the file names or an array of the `InputStream` references to the files. But you can't store the text files per se. You could also store the contents of the text files as strings.